# Take latest Log File & store in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, datetime, grep

I'm looking for a solution to grep the latest log file (say abc-20141028-005356.log), which was modified. I can do this with command "ls -1t  |head -1" , which gives solution, but there are other files which gets modified in the log folder too.. I tried doing with a head -2 which gives 2 files & then grepped the file... Say "ls -1t | head -2 | grep abc-".

The real problem is when we have the same filename with latest data & new time & date. How do i store the latest logfile to a variable which has the same duplicate file names & tailing with date & time.

```
PATH=`cd $1 ; ls -1t | head -1`
LOGFILE=$1$PATH
```

$1=/opt/server1/logs/

Kindly please advise on the same

I'm not able to grep a unique file based o the time stamp, for an instance abc-20141028-005356.log is modified & the next file is abc-20141028-005358.log, which is a time diff only.. but the complete file name remains same.

Need a solution where in i can assign the latest file modified to a variable irrespective of the file name & timestamp ( modified latest)

```
I have couple of files here

total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:14 abc-20141028-005348.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:14 abc-20141028-005358.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:19 abc-20141029-005358.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:19 abc-20141029-005360.log

This is the latest file i get if i use the below

[root@abcd RKP]# ls -1t | head -1
abc-20141029-005360.log

The above can be done when there is only files starting with abcd-***. Now i have the below files

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:14 abc-20141028-005348.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:14 abc-20141028-005358.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:19 abc-20141029-005358.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:19 abc-20141029-005360.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:21 EFG-20141028-005348.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:21 EFG-20141028-005358.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 11:21 EFG-20141029-005358.log

When i do the above command 

[root@abcd RKP]# ls -1t | head -1
EFG-20141029-005358.log

I want only files which are modified on abcd-XXXXX.XXXX based on the last modfied time.

I'm sorry for making this so confused. Please let me know if you need anything more.

The solution may be simple, but I'm not getting how to do this. !!!!
```

Thanks that worked....

Thank you ... That worked. While running the above in my script i get this error                                                       line 30: [: : integer expression expected

Any idea what I'm  missing. The script for the same part is below.

```
 if [ -e $POSFile ]; then
# Read last Position
lastPosition=`cat $POSFile`
fi
fileLength=`stat -c %s $LOGFILE`

if [ "$lastPosition" -gt "$fileLength" ]; then
# Log file rolled
lastPosition=0;
fi

difference=`expr $fileLength - $lastPosition`
# New Spot  To POSFile

    enter code here

echo $fileLength > $POSFile
```

Comment: Can you explain that "The real problem" bit again? I don't understand what you were trying to indicate there. Also you can probably just use `"$1"` in the `ls` directly and not need to `cd` and concatenate the variables in the assignment.

Comment: I need to grep the latest logfile based on time of the modification. The file should have latest data in it.  Log files are same... abcd-YYMMDD-TIME.log

Comment: You mean the datestamp of the file isn't enough to find the right file? You need the actual modification time of the file? Older stamped files might be the most recent file you actually need to look at?

Comment: How do i assign the latest modified file to a variable based on timestamp ?

Comment: Is your script not working correctly?

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you show the output of `ls -l` on two files like that when your script doesn't work correctly? And if the time part of the filename changes then the file name does not remain the same.

Comment: You only want files that start `abc-`? `ls -1t "$1/abc-* | head -n 1`?

Comment: [root@abcd RKP]# cd /tmp/RK/  ; ls -1t "/tmp/RK/abc-*" | head -n 1
ls: /tmp/RK/abc-*: No such file or directory
[root@abcd RKP]# d /tmp/RK/  ; ls -1t "abc-*" | head -n 1                   ls: abc-*: No such file or directory

Comment: You appear to have missed `P` in those path names (i.e. `RK` instead of `RKP`). And you don't need the cd with the full path to `ls`.

Comment: cd /tmp/RK/  ; ls -1t abc-* | head -n1                                   abc-20141030-005360.log                                               This works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest file starting with `abc-` in some directory `$1`:

```
ls -t "$1"/abc-* | head -n1
```

If no file matches this pattern, you get a `No such file or directory` error. In that case check the value of `$1`. Some helpful commands:

```
echo $1
ls "$1"
ls "$1"/abc-*
```

The little script snippet in your post should be:

```
LOGFILE=$(ls -t "$1"/abc-* | head -n1)
```

I also noticed that you're trying to set `PATH=` to something. That might not end well. The `PATH` variable in the shell is special, it contains the list of paths where the shell looks for executable files. Use a different name for the variable, for example `path=` will be fine (all lowercased).

As for the second part of your question:

> line 30: [: : integer expression expected

This must come from this line:

> ```
> if [ "$lastPosition" -gt "$fileLength" ]; then
> ```

Both sides of the `-gt` must be integers for this to work. Add some `echo` lines to check if those variables are really numeric, for example:

```
echo lastPosition=$lastPosition
echo fileLength=$fileLength
if [ "$lastPosition" -gt "$fileLength" ]; then
```

Also, it would be better to rewrite all your `` `...` `` with `$(...)`.

Comment: Thank you Janos & Etan.. that worked                                   I've updated the Question part with another querry. Please suggest for the same

Comment: @RKP It would be better to keep one question per post. But I tried to address this part too and updated my post.